# Lookup and join dataframes with multiple column names in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**df1:**

```
col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        col6        col7        col8 
7865                                                                                abc
                                    7269                                            def
            8726                                                                    ghi
                                                                        986         jkl
                                                7689                                mno
                        8762                                                        pqr
                                                                                    stu
                        9698                                                        vwx
            3568                                                                    yz
```

**df2:**

```
Scientific value         mapping_value
1                        8726
2                        9698
3                        3568
4                        986
5                        7269
```

I want to match "col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7" column values in df1 with "mapping_value" column in df2 and create a new column called "Scientific value" in df1 which would have entries from "Scientific value" column in df2.

**Output:**

```
col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        col6        col7        col8   Scientific value
7865                                                                                abc    
                                    7269                                            def    5
            8726                                                                    ghi    1
                                                                        986         jkl    4
                                                7689                                mno
                        8762                                                        pqr
                                                                                    stu
                        9698                                                        vwx    2
            3568                                                                    yz     3
```

Would merge work in this case..or would be happy to learn any other efficient method as well!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only one number per rows for any of column without last solution should be simplify by `sum`, `max`, `min` function for one column, so is possible use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df2.set_index('mapping_value')['Scientific value']
df1['Scientific value'] = df1.iloc[:, :-1].max(axis=1).map(s)
#if empty string are not missing values
#df1['Scientific value'] = df1.iloc[:, :-1].replace('',np.nan).max(axis=1).map(s)
```

If possible multiple values first select by position by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), remove possible missing values for non match values and last aggregate lists:

```
s = df2.set_index('mapping_value')['Scientific value']
df1['Scientific value'] = (df1.iloc[:, :-1]
                              .stack()
                              .map(s)
                              .dropna()
                              .groupby(level=0)
                              .agg(list))
```

Comment: sorry for the additional doubt @jezrael I have now. In cases where I want to mention the column names from col1 to col7 instead of .iloc positions, how would I do that with `.loc[]`

Comment: When using 2nd approach(where multiple values possible) @jezrael, I get output values like `[5]` instead of `5`. When I checked `print(type(df1['Scientific value']))`, it gives `'<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`, how can I get normal output values as in 1st approach you had given

Comment: @omdurg - I think it is data dependent, is possivble create new question with this multiple output values?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I have posted it

Comment: @omdurg - do you test posted data with this problem Do you get `[5]` instead `5`?

Comment: With extended data quite bigger than the posted one @jezrael, the first approach working fine, but that when multiple values are possible I am getting a `[ ]`, so when I export to sqlserver, it says that column is a `array of array`

Comment: @omdurg - It seems there are some duplicates. So data are different like sample...